# In Ocaml, is there a way to implement the function pop of a stack?

Tags: stack, ocaml

Instead of using the module Stack, I want to build a pop function by myself.

The function I implemented is:

```
let pop (stack_lst:stack) = match stack_lst with
  | [] -> None
  | [x] -> x
  | hd::tl -> hd
```

Soon I realize that my function only gives the top frame, however, my function does not remove the top frame from the stack. In such a sense, the frame still remains. Since OCaml gives me immutable data structure, what should I do?

In addition to my question, my data type is defined as:

```
location = Obj of int | Null
and
environment = (var * location) list
and
frame = Decl of environment | Call of environment * stack 
and 
stack = frame list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just have to return a new stack without the popped element as well. Additionally, you're returning an `option` if the stack is empty, but not in the other branches, which I've also fixed here:

```
let pop (stack_lst: stack) = match stack_lst with
  | [] -> (None, [])
  | [x] -> (Some x, [])
  | hd::tl -> (Some hd, tl)
```

or

```
let pop (stack_lst: stack) = match stack_lst with
  | [] -> None
  | [x] -> Some (x, [])
  | hd::tl -> Some (hd, tl)
```

Comment: Thank you! So 1. what the is functionality of this tuple? 2. Without some, why does it not work?

Comment: Got it, it is tuple since I want to return two arguments, the first argument is the frame, the second argument is the stack list. It is Some due to the data structure of Module Option. I can convert from Some x to x by defining a get function. Thanks.

Comment: Basically correct, but you could just pattern match on the `option` value. It's nothing more than an ordinary variant type: `type 'a option = None | Some of 'a`. The `Option` module is just a container for convenience functions that operate on the `option` type. The type itself isn't even defined in the `Option` module, just aliased there, and the module has no privileged access to the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for the moment whether it's idiomatic, or the complexity implications - OCaml *does* support mutable state, which could be used to address something like a stack.

```
# type 'a stack = { mutable lst : 'a list };;
type 'a stack = { mutable lst : 'a list; }
# let a = { lst = [1; 3; 4] };;
val a : int stack = {lst = [1; 3; 4]}
# let pop = function
  | {lst=[]} -> None
  | {lst=(x::xs)} as s -> s.lst <- xs; Some x;;
val pop : 'a stack -> 'a option = <fun>
# pop a;;
- : int option = Some 1
# a;;
- : int stack = {lst = [3; 4]}
# pop a;;
- : int option = Some 3
# a;;
- : int stack = {lst = [4]}
#
```